# Find x from a given y in a spline function in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, spline, approximation, bspline

What is the correct way of finding `x` from a given `y` from a spline function?

```
library(cobs)
library(tidyverse)

# data
dat <- tibble(
  x = c(seq(80, 360, 40),373.3),
  y = c(1.07, .85, .84, .97, 1.11, 2.02, 4.01, 7.99, 10.4)
)

# interpolation
dat_interpolated <- approx(x = dat$x, y = dat$y, xout = seq(min(dat$x), max(dat$x), 1)) %>% 
  as.tibble()

# spline
myspline <- cobs(x = dat_interpolated$x, y = dat_interpolated$y)

# data for plotting
dat2 <- predict(myspline) %>% 
  as.tibble()

dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, y))+
  geom_point(shape = 21,
             size = 4,
             fill = "white")+
  geom_line(data = dat2, aes(z, fit), size = 1, color = "red")+
  theme_bw()
```

**Plot:**

[image]

**Expected outcome:**

My goal is to correctly find `x` when:

- `y == 2`
- `y == 3`
- `y == 4`

Comment: That's nice, I will check it out!

Comment: Okay, I am not sure this is a duplicate, as this won't work when I use splines fitted with the `cobs` package (which seems to be the best option in my particular case)